# Angular 2 doesn't recognize DOM change

Tags: javascript, angular

I using some angular 2 components in my project, and I need to change some of component's position. I use DOM to change the position first, like replaceChild or insertBefore, something like that. But I notice that angular 2 doesn't know the DOM change, seems like my DOM change is over the angular 2 life cycle. **So, is there any way I can edit DOM in angular2 ? or some way I can change the order of components?**

For you can understand what I'm doing, I'm building some components and I want to drag them and switch their position. I find a plug-in write in JQuery, you can find a gif on its GitHub site (https://github.com/Barrior/DDSort/blob/master/img/ddsort.gif). I want to implement something like that gif.

I find something maybe help on GitHub, but I don't know how to use it. 
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/linker/view_manager.ts

Comment: Have you tried using $scope.$apply() ?

Comment: @Dan, I'm using angular2. It's a mistake I use angular tag. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this was asked a while ago, but for others that might be struggling with something like this... Angular uses zones which I believe monkey-patch asynchronous JavaScript operations.

To trigger DOM updates that might not otherwise be picked up by Angular, you can run your with zones...

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {

    constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

    someFunction() {
        this.zone.run(() => {
            // Your code goes here!
        });
    }

}
```

Take a look at this [blog on zones](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html)

Answer (score 0):

To follow the best practice, developers should use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) to modify/use DOM. Here is an [example](https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/) to show how to use ViewChild to get a DOM element. You can use a "#" to mark the element you want to use and get it on your component.

If you want to get a collection of child elements in a component you should use [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren).

The question was asked when I started to Learn Angular, it's stupid question and I believe there are many beginners like manipulate DOM directly. Please update your DOM in "Angular Way".